# Am I allowed to talk about this?

Tags: support, closed-questions, android

I keep getting my posts closed whenever I ask for a place where I could find information about telnet clients.

I'm working on an Android application and I wouldn't want to post my program since it is not complete. I'm trying to learn how to write it all by myself, but I lack information. That is why I asked this question on the site. Both of my posts were closed.

The closed questions are:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13894075/android-telnet-client-with-microchip-telnet-server
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14003818/good-forum-for-this

Comment: Stack Overflow is *not* a forum but a Question and Answer site; that's an important distiction. Have you got links to your two questions?

Comment: @Phyziik Thanks for taking the time to come to Meta and ask this question.  Too often, new users either just keep posting the same thing or ragequit the site without taking time to figure it out. :)  Welcome!

Comment: What you're dealing with here is telnet, which is an established and [well documented](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc854.txt) protocol. Imagine that you have a magic wand that can take away all other complexities other than socket I/O and then wave it. Problem logging in? Ask a question, show _just_ the code that tries to authenticate,  explain what you've tried as far as debugging goes and in a few minutes someone will tell you what's wrong.

Comment: First of all, thanks for these comments, it's always better then being directly closed. Second, it's my mistake, my client is a android app and my server is a microchip unit. I understand that this protocol is well documented since I looked through a lot of pages. Problem is: applying is to a android application. I will try to find some more information.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I'm looking at your latest question, ignoring the irrelevant title and introduction.

> Where could I get infos related to communication between Android and Microchip.

That's not a Stack Overflow question. That's something you look up using a search engine and the product documentation. The web has tons of information on client/server setups, in pretty much all the languages you could care for. Forums and chat rooms can work for that too, if you're looking for pointers.

> I'm trying to make a Android application which would be a telnet server since my Microchip unit is a telnet server.

Ok, this would be a good start for a Stack Overflow question, except for the issue that the logical structure doesn't grok: if you've got a server on your Microchip, the logical thing to implement on your Android device would be a client, not another server. Let's assume it's a typo to try and make sense of the rest.

> My server is working all fine.

Ok, this looks good too... but hey, wait a second. Which one of the devices is that? Let's hope the rest of it clears this up.

> All I need is an app that can receive and respond correctly.

And this is not a Stack Overflow question (or at least, doesn't appear to be). It reads as if you're asking for someone to recommend you an existing app that could work with your Microchip device. Or your phone. (At this point I'm completely confused about what part of what you've got you're asking about.)

And that's the whole of your question. I don't see how anyone could help you there.

You need to explain exactly what you are trying to do, as clearly and simply as possible.

What device are you programming on - the Android one or the Microchip one? Both? What part of that have you successfully implemented so far? What part, specifically, is giving you problems?

Show the relevant parts of what you've got, even if it doesn't compile (show the compiler errors in that case), doesn't work (show the error messages/stack trace/problematic behavior), or is only pseudo-code. Or show the client part if you can't figure out how to get the server part to work with it (someone might explain a different way of writing the client part to make the server part more obvious/easier to code). Or vice-versa.

Comment: Excellent answer! :) In my mind, to make it perfect, you could also mention the importance of having a good, meaningful title that describes what the problem is.

Comment: @Mat I understand that not all of my post/question was clear and well structured. Reason is, I don't know what I can say or ask since I keep getting closed... So I just went all out with simple and direct explanation. I posted my program to get help with it, not to get someone to do the whole job for me. First thing I get: "Won't work" end of the line. I'm totally new to java/sdk/android language so yes I have to go through a lot of infos I don't clearly understand, but since I'm working on a communication that seems to be "unclear" to many developpers, I end up being all alone on this. Thanks

Comment: @Phyziik: Stack Overflow isn't the place to go if you can't get started, or are missing some fundamentals. It's not a place where people will walk you through a topic as large as client/server programming or "learning java/sdk/android". Read books and search the web for tutorials to get the grasp of the technology (there is _a lot_ of information out there on those topics). Go to Stack Overflow when you're stuck on a specific implementation problem you can't figure out. You're not alone on this, the web is full of information about the topic put there by thousands of other developers.